# Minimum number of times a sorted array rotated

Tags: python

You are given list of numbers, obtained by rotating a sorted list an unknown number of times. Write a function to determine the minimum number of times the original sorted list was rotated to obtain the given list. Your function should have the worst-case complexity of O(log N), where N is the length of the list. You can assume that all the numbers in the list are unique.

Example: The list [5, 6, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4] was obtained by rotating the sorted list [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9] 3 times.

We define "rotating a list" as removing the last element of the list and adding it before the first element. E.g. rotating the list [3, 2, 4, 1] produces [1, 3, 2, 4].

"Sorted list" refers to a list where the elements are arranged in the increasing order e.g. [1, 3, 5, 7].

The program I wrote is:

```
def binary_search(low,high,condition):

while low<=high:

        mid=(low+high)//2

        result=condition(mid)

        if result=="found":

            return mid

        elif result == "left":

            high = mid-1

        elif result == "right":

            low=mid+1

    return -1
 
def min_times_of_rotation(nums):

    def condition(mid):

        N=len(nums)

        next=(mid+1)%N

        prev=(mid+N-1)%N

        low=0

        high=len(nums)-1

        if nums[mid]<=prev and nums[mid]<=next:

            return mid

        elif nums[low]<=nums[mid]:

            return "right"

        elif nums[mid]<=nums[high]:

            return "left"

    return binary_search(0,len(nums)-1,condition)
    

nums=[8,4,3,6,7,9,2]

print(min_times_of_rotation(nums))
```

**Here in this program i am unable to get the output, it is printing nothing in my console.So please help me to find the error in my program.**

Comment: In your example, it sesms that nums is not the result of the rotation of a sorted list.

Comment: What's with all the empty lines, why do you want us to not be able to see all your code at once?

Comment: 1/ Can you summarize you algorithm in a short sentence? 2/ Why do you use a binary search as the result seems quite easy?

Comment: @hpchavaz What do you mean with "Why do you use a binary search as the result seems quite easy?"?

Comment: The result is obviously the index of the max (1 based) modulo the length of the sequence. Why use a binary search?

Comment: @hpchavaz Because *"Your function should have the worst-case complexity of O(log N)"*.

Comment: @KellyBundy, oh, sorry.

Comment: @Naheeda, you wrote "You are given list of numbers, obtained by rotating a sorted list", but the input nums=[8,4,3,6,7,9,2] is not rotated sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

In a sorted list that's rotated several times, you'll notice that the minimum value is the only element that is less than its previous element.

For example, in  [5, 6, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4], '0' is the only element that's less than its previous value 9. Every other element is greater than its previous value.

We will use this property to do a binary search to find the index of the minimum value which gives us the number of rotations.

```
def min_times_of_rotation(nums):
    n = len(nums)
    start = 0
    end = n-1
# index of minimum of the array would be equal to number to rotation
# Only the minimum value will be less than its previous value
# Binary search
    while start<=end:
        mid = start+(end-start)//2
# Calculating the previous(prev) index of mid
        prev = mid-1
# Checking if mid is minimum
        if nums[mid]<nums[prev]: 
            return mid
# if we didn't find min value, then change limits
        elif nums[mid]<nums[start]: 
            end = mid-1
        elif nums[mid]>nums[end]: 
            start = mid+1
        else: 
            return 0

x = [5, 6, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4]
print(min_times_of_rotation(x))

x = [6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]
print(min_times_of_rotation(x))
```

Outout:

```
3
4
```